# After attaching a formatted hard disk, my computer is not starting?

Tags: windows-7, motherboard, formatting

I have formatted my hard disk in my friend computer. His configuration is P4 processor and an Intel 845 series motherboard.
Now I have attached the hard disk in my computer, but after attaching my computer is not starting.

My computer configuration is a P4 processor and mercury pi845gnm mother board.
I am not able to format my hard disk in my computer (mercury motherboard). And also what is setting for boot priority for formatting hard disk in mercury pi845gvm.

Comment: Did you install windows when it was on the other computer? could be a simple matter of differing hardware.  Does the computer start without the hard drive connected? A PIV is *pretty* old, and some models got hit by bad capasitors so hardware failure is a possibility here.

Comment: You haven't said what kind of disk this is but many [ATA drives have jumpers](http://eshop.macsales.com/Tech/manuals/idehdsettings/Maxtor72.pdf) that determine whether it's master or slave.  If they're both set to master, you'll have a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there more than one drive in the computer?*

Given the age of that motherboard (I can't find that exact model after a quick look on the Mercury website, but there are others from that era), it could be something to do with the old Master/Slave configuration with the IDE channel.

There are two things to check, the back of the drive should have a small "jumper" on it, which specifies "what" the drive is.

The label on the HDD should depict how to place the jumper, but this image should give you a pretty good idea:

[image: HDD Jumper Positions]

If it is the only drive in the system, remove the jumper completely.

If you have two drives on the same IDE cable, the one you want to boot from should be master, and the other should be slave.

It may also be the case that the position on the cable determines which drive is master and which is slave. From memory the master should be the one at the end of the cable.

[image: IDE Cable, master and slave]

Comment: I'm quite sure there's also a cable detect configuration